# How do I make a web server accessible though the internet?

Tags: jquery, node.js, web, web-deployment

I have created a basic web server using node.js which listens to port 3000 on my desktop. It serves static HTML files (jQuery mobile documents actually).

I am able to access the site on the local host (my Windows 7 desktop) using `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`.

I want to be able to access the site from my mobile over the internet.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexible solution (not for production, but easy, and without need to configure routers) is using localhost tunnel services, since you are on node.js, there is already one available:

[localtunnel](https://www.npmjs.org/package/localtunnel). To use it:

1. npm install -g localtunnel
2. lt --port 3000
3. Share the url it provides

*Reasoning against using it in production:*

1. You rely on good-will of the intermediate service. Clients will communicate with that 'tunnel', and who knows whether it is sniffing the sensitive data, or injects some information. Probably not, but you will never be given a guarantee.
2. Down-time of this tunnel service will affect you. As it is free, I would expect the service quality as high as the money you pay for it.
3. The overall idea of those localhost tunnels is for easier development process. Letting your friends see the site and give a feedback without much of a hassle. It might even be against their policy to run a high-load website through a tunnel.

Comment: Why is this not for production? How secure is localtunnel — is it basically as secure as whatever is being used as a server (in this case, node.js), or are there other risks? Safer than just opening port forwarding on the router?

Comment: Instead of the command line, I used the node API to generate a tunnel, each time I run the server.js.

Comment: server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening at port 3000.');
    localtunnel(3000,function(err,tunnel){
        if(err)console.log('error setting up tunnel to localhost');
        else console.log("Site accessible at : "+tunnel.url);
    });
});

Comment: Adding the code right into application is indeed a step forward for automation..  @iamnotmaynard, Why not advised for production? Added thoughts into my answer.

Comment: Good reasons. Any thoughts on the security of this method?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Plenty. How would you even implement HTTPS? Register a certificate to always changing URL? Register it to URL you are not owning? There is no security, as a site author in the end owns nothing - no domain, nor IP.

Comment: Can this be use in production?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, old question but for future me, you can nowadays use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

> Secure tunnels to localhost
>
> ”I want to expose a local server behind a NAT or firewall to the internet.”

Of course **not for production**, but perfect to develop webhooks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into port forwarding on your router.  Set the port forward for HTML requests to 3000.  Then find out what your router's IP address is.

Then use `http://[routerIP]:port/` to access your site.

And pray you don't get hacked like mad for opening up that port with no security.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use nginx, Here is an example.

```
upstream app_myapp {
server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name www.myhost.com myhost.com;

location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://app_myapp/;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Comment: It seems like OP already has a server up and running using node.js; I think the question is how to then access it from outside the local machine/network.

Comment: I misunderstood.  I thought he wanted to run his app on a port 3000 but access it from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not a safe and secure option. 
As you're using nodejs, have you considered deploying your app as PaaS plateform as heroku.com ? 
The options listed are all functional, but not recommended: You need to use an external service to serve your files.